# How do you procedurally rotate an image in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics

I want procedurally rotate an image in WPF.  I've seen how to bind a rotation to a control.  But, I want to bind the rotation to an object's angle.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

```
<Image Source="{Binding ElementName=ImageList,Path=SelectedItem.Image}">
   <Image.LayoutTransform>
      <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RotationProperty}"/>
   </Image.LayoutTransform>
</Image>
```

Source + more info:
http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2007/11/15/wpf-image-viewer-part-7-rotating-the-image-with-a.aspx